# Create vector field out scalar field

Tags: matlab

Hi I have an n by n matrix, z, which denotes the scalar values in the z dimension of a vector field. i.e.

```
z = 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

the scalar field values in the x and y dimensions are 0. My question is how do I take z and form the vector field. I have tried something like:

```
x = zeros(size(z));
y = x;
vecfield = [x(:) y(:) z(:)]
```

where I would be expecting:

```
vecfield(:,:1) = 

    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

 vecfield(:,:2) = 

    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

 vecfield(:,:3) = 

    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

However I am getting:

```
vecfield = 

    0 0 1
    0 0 2
    0 0 3
    0 0 4
    . . .
    . . .
```

and so on. Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the expression `x(:)` does not return the array `x`, it returns a vector containing the elements of `x` in storage order.  Try this at the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your trying to create 3 separate n by n matrixes and are forcing them into  the wrong dimensions. Instead,

```
vecfield = zeros(size(z),length(z),3) %because you want three arrays in the z direction
```

then,
    vecfield(:,:,3) = z;

OR you are trying to take the scalar values of Z and use them as an indicator of z-dimension size of the vecfield. This is impossible because the dimensions settings would not be uniform. However, you can still *represent* that information by numbering the cells that are in your vecfield and making everything else zero. Then it would look like...

vecfield(:,:,1)

1 2 3 2 1

1 2 3 2 1

1 2 3 2 1

then,
    vecfield(:,:,2)

0 1 2 1 0

0 1 2 1 0

0 1 2 1 0

then,
    vecfield(:,:,3)

0 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0 0

etc

We can do that (the idea of it, obviously using your n by n dimensions). something like this maybe,

```
vecfield = zeros(size(z),length(z),max(max(z)));
for n  = 1 : size(vecfield,3)
     vecfield(:,:,n) = z(:,:)- n;
     vecfield((vecfield(:,:,n) < 0)==1) = 0;
end
```

hope that helped!

Comment: wanted to avoid a for loop if possible, but this gets the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

> vecfield = cat(3, x,y,z)

Answer (score 1):

No need to create `x` and `y` explicitly:

```
z = [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1;
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1;
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1;
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1;
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1];

vecfield = z; % vecfield 5 x 9 (x 1)
vecfield(:,:,2:3) = 0;
```

The last command dynamically extends vecfield to the third dimension, sets all values to zero.